# How do I get the string with name of a class?

Tags: python

What method do I call to get the name of a class?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

```
In [1]: class Test:
   ...:     pass
   ...: 

In [2]: Test.__name__
Out[2]: 'Test'
```

Answer (score 46):

It's not a method, it's a field.  The field is called `__name__`.  `class.__name__` will give the name of the class as a string.  `object.__class__.__name__` will give the name of the class of an object.

Comment: Better written as `type(object).__name__`.

Answer (score 13):

I agree with Mr.Shark, but if you have an instance of a class, you'll need to use its `__class__` member:

```
>>> class test():
...     pass
...
>>> a_test = test()
>>>
>>> a_test.__name__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: test instance has no attribute '__name__'
>>>
>>> a_test.__class__
<class __main__.test at 0x009EEDE0>
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped dynamically naming a new class created with `type` and multiple bases. (e.g.: `type('_'.join(x.__name__ for x in bases), bases, {})`)

Answer (score 5):

From [**Python 3.3**](https://docs.python.org/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-3155-qualified-name-for-classes-and-functions) and onwards we can use [`__qualname__` field](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#definition.__qualname__) for both classes & functions.

It differs from [`__name__` field](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#definition.__name__) for nested objects like a class defined in other class

```
>>> class A:
        class B:
            pass
>>> A.B.__name__
'B'
>>> A.B.__qualname__
'A.B'
```

which may be quite useful.

## Further reading

- [PEP 3155 -- Qualified name for classes and functions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3155/).

Answer (score 1):

In [8]: `str('2'.__class__)`
Out[8]: `"<type 'str'>"`

In [9]: `str(len.__class__)`
Out[9]: `"<type 'builtin_function_or_method'>"`

In [10]: `str(4.6.__class__)`
Out[10]: `"<type 'float'>"`

Or, as was pointed out before,

In [11]: `4.6.__class__.__name__`
Out[11]: `'float'`

Comment: I think your underscores got eaten by markdown.  You meant:

    4.6.4.6.__class__.__name__

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the name inside the context of the class itself with `self.__class__.__name__` or just `__class__.__name__`.

```
>>> class A:
...     def __init__(self):
...         # These are equivalent...
...         print(self.__class__.__name__)
...         print(__class__.__name__)
...         print(A.__name__)
... 
>>> a = A()
A
A
A
>>>
```